# Google Analytics setup for 3 related blogs

Tags: google-analytics

I have 3 distinct blogs.
They are powered by Wordpress Multisite

http://blogs.crocus.co.uk/kitchengarden
http://blogs.crocus.co.uk/chelseaflowershow
http://blogs.crocus.co.uk/plantsmans

What I want to do is set up Goolge Analytics to track them

What would be the best way to do this?

A separate account for each?
A "Blogs" account, with different profiles... etc..?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up Google Analytics for multiple sites under one client, I tend to use one account and multiple profiles. Just keeps it together nicely.

To be honest, whatever works for you and makes life easier for you is the best way. I don't think there's a right or wrong way.